# C# Application with Numerous Errors

Tags: c#

I am having fun with a couple of errors I am getting in a C# application I am writing.
The error I keep getting is:

- encrypt and decrypt calls must have a return type
- Console.WriteLine being used as a method
- static void encrypt(string[] args) expected class, delegate, interface or struct

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string pw ="", hash =""; //Declare an intialise variables

            if (args.Length < 4) // Test to see if correct number of arguments have been passed
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please use command line arguments in this format: encrypt -e (or -d) password-to-encrypt-with input-file output-file");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            if (args[1].Length < 10 || args[1].Length > 40) // Test to see if the password is between 10 and 40 characters
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please use a password between 10 and 40 characters");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            switch (args[0]) //Uses first argument value to drive switch statement (-e or -d)
            {
                case "-e":
                encrypt(string[] args);
                break;

                case "-d":
                decrypt(string[] args);
                break;

                default:
                Console.WriteLine("When using the program please use -e to encrypt and -d to decrypt");
                break;
            }        
        } //End of MAIN

        static void encrypt(string[] args)  //Function to encrypt
        {
            string inputtext =""; //Initialise Varible (Ensure it is empty)
            inputtext=System.IO.File.ReadAllText(args[2]); //Read file in an assign to input text
            return;
        }

        static void decrypt(string[] args)  //Function to decrypt
        {
            string inputtext =""; //Initialise Varible (Ensure it is empty)
            inputtext=System.IO.File.ReadAllText(args[2]); //Read file in an assign to input text
            return;
        }
    }  
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!
Alistair

Comment: You do not need to initialize variables, just before you give them another value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When calling a method, you must not specify the types of the arguments. So:

```
        case "-e":
        encrypt(args);
        break;
```

Answer (score 2):

Along with what Hans has said, you mentioned an error about return types in your methods.

Your `encrypt` and `decrypt` methods have `return` statements, but they are `void` methods meaning they don't have any return types.

Either give it a type you want to return (presumably the string you are manipulating) or just remove the `return` statement altogether. You do not need to explicitly put `return` at the end of a method to get it to exit out of the method. It will do that anyway.

Two small pro-tips, I would declare your fields on different lines, not all bunched together (with the way you have declared `pw` and `hash`) and also add a using directive for `System.IO`, so you don't have to call `System.IO.File.ReadAllText`, you can just call `File.ReadAllText`.